# search query suggestion youtube API on Production results in Cors Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, youtube-api

I want the search suggestions like of Youtube on my application to work on Production as well.

The website is hosted on Firebase.

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=Query

I am using this API to fetch the results. The Results work on localhost but not on Production.

[https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q='](https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=%27) from origin 'website hosted on Firebase' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What should I do?

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="upgrade-insecure-requests"
    />
```

I added this tag in the Index file but it still did not resolve the Error